# Laravel Factory Pattern issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have created a class called `Provider`

```
class Provider
{

    private $provider;

    public function __construct(ProviderInterface $provider)
    {
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }
}
```

In the factory class, I have this:

```
class ProviderFactory
{
  public static function adapt(string $provider)
  {
    switch ($provider) {
            case 'ProviderOne':
               return app(Provider::class, [app(ProviderOne::class)]);
            case 'ProviderTwo':
               return app(Provider::class, [app(ProviderTwo::class)]);
        }
   }
}
```

When calling `ProviderFactory::adapt($request->provider)` I get an error:

```
Target [App\Services\ProviderInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Services\Provider].
```

If I understand correctly I need `bind()` logic as it needs to know what to bind to the `ProviderInterface`. Do I need add `bind()` logic in the service provider?

Answer (score 0):

Add below to the register function of your service provider I am assuming that your interface has the namespace as below

```
$this->app->bind('App\Services\ProviderInterface');
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `$provider` be public?

```
class Provider
{

  public $provider;

  public function __construct(ProviderInterface $provider)
  {
    $this->provider = $provider;
  }
}
```